# Why is my function not executiong my global variable?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var number = "10";

  (function(){
    alert(number);    
    alert(eval('number=22'));

  })();

  var func = function() {
      alert (new Function( 'return (' + number + ')' )());
  }

  func(); // prints 22.

</script>
```

It first alerts `10`, then alerts `22` then why is it alerting `22 again instead of 10`. Does eval function overrides my variable in global scope.

Comment: @pst Why `new Function ... ` instead of `(function() ... )`?

Comment: @WaleedKhan To keep with the ridiculousness. However, the "real" issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `eval` isn't executed in the global scope but you don't have a variable named `number` in your local scope. So you're changing the global one.

You may see it with this little change :

```
(function(){
  var number; // this will ensure the global number isn't changed
  alert(number);  // this will print "undefined"
  alert(eval('number=22')); // this won't change the global variable
})();
```

Note that `alert(eval('number=22'));` returns the result of the evaluation and `number=22` returns `22`. That's why the second alert gives `22`.

Comment: I don't have a variable in local scope, but why is it taking the value 22 instead of 10 when eval is executed in the same context

Comment: I don't get your question. `number=22` changes the value to `22`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a variable in your local scope, its changing the global one. Try this one below. It would print 100 instead of 22.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


  var number = 100;

  (function(){
    var number;
    alert(number);    
    alert(eval('number=22'));

  })();

  function func() {
      alert (new Function( 'return (' + number + ')' )());
  }

  func();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### eval is evil

[don't use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea).

If you remove the use of eval what is happening is maybe more obvious - you are redefining the value of the global variable `number` inside the first anonymous function:

```
var number = "10";

(function(){
    number = 22; // this is a reference to the global variable `number`
})();

var func = function() {
    alert (new Function( 'return (' + number + ')' )()); // this is another use of eval - don't do this
}

func(); // prints 22 - expected.
```

Comment: This is fine... it would change the global one, but in the case above i am using eval... does that too do the same thing.

Comment: @Kevin er.. yes. that's the point. eval just executes the evaluated code wherever you've put it. It is not a magic execution sandbox.

Comment: and since its not able to find any variable in its scope, it changes the global scope which also gets reflected in other function... sorry for the trouble...